# Redirect stdout to a variable while requiring other script

Tags: perl, stdout

I'm trying to redirect STDOUT to a variable, which seems to work fine. However, when I'm requiring other script, its expected output is not stored in that variable.

```
my $var;

#save STDOUT for future redirect
open OLDOUT, '>&STDOUT';
close STDOUT;

# redirect STDOUT to $var 
open STDOUT, '>', \$var or die "Can't open STDOUT: $!";

# run the script that I'm supposed to catch its output
do("macro.pl");
close STDOUT;

# redirect STDOUT to its original FH
open STDOUT, '>&OLDOUT' or die "Can't restore stdout: $!";
close OLDOUT or die "Can't close OLDOUT: $!";

# print the expected result from macro.pl
print "$var";
```

The last line prints nothing, which is not the expected result (running macro.pl alone yields a non-empty output).

Tried it also with require - same result.
It is worth mentioning that macro.pl doesn't - in any way - changes the standard file descriptors.

Thanks!

Comment: This works fine for me. What is in `macro.pl`? You should try it with a `macro.pl` that contains just a single `print` statement. *And always* `use strict` and `use warnings`!

Comment: Actually, replacing it with a different script works. what can be the cause of the different behavior of macro.pl (it is a quite heavy script that requiring other scripts and running system command, but non of them redirect STDOUT)?

Comment: Where does your output go to? Does it appear on the console? Are you sure the output from `macro.pl` isn't to `STDERR`? Are you trying to capture output made suring a `use` statement, in which case you need a `BEGIN` block around the code redirecting `STDOUT`. Try adding a `print` statement at the beginning of `macro.pl` to see if that goes to your `$var` variable.

Comment: 1) The output strangely disappear. 2) `STDERR` is empty while running the script. 3) Tried using  `BEGIN` around the redirection - still missing output. 4) Tried adding a print at the beginning of macro.pl - still empty output. 5) This is getting weird, appreciate your help! :)

Comment: OK you need to keep debugging. Trying this remotely without sight of the code isn't really effective, but I'll take a look if you want to put your `macro.pl` on a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or similar. My next step would be to add `exit` directly after the new `print` statement, as I suspect the problem is within the `use` statements.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that printing in the "parent" script (the one I've quoted its code) after the redirection to `$var` does save the output in $var. Only the printed output of `macro.pl` (and its sub-scripts) is missing...

Comment: one more thing: I've found that the sub-script that its output doesn't get printed is called via `system(script_name.pl)`. do you think that it has something to do with it?

Comment: That is the problem. System starts a new process that has its own STDOUT (although my Unix isn't good enough to know where new STDOUT is opened to). If you run the program in your question with `system` instead of `do` then your output will vanish in the same way. I suggest you use `print qx/script_name.pl/` instead of `system`. That way the output from the child script is collected by the parent and printed to its own STDOUT.

Answer (score 3):

You need to [`select`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/select.html) the filehandle in order to make it the default filehandle (aka `STDOUT`). Try it like this.

```
my $printBuffer; # Your output will go in here
open(my $buffer, '>', \$printBuffer);
my $stdout = select($buffer); # $stdout is the original STDOUT

do 'macro.pl';

select($stdout); # go back to the original
close($buffer);

print $printBuffer;
```

Comment: Thanks, But this doesn't work. It doesn't even redirect STDOUT, such that the program does print macro.pl output, but $printBuffer is empty.

Comment: That's strange. It works for me. Did you replace your code with this?

Comment: I know this is an old post. But i have been chasing the same issue. I tried this. I doesn't work for me.

Comment: @davison see above comment by Borodin on the question.