# How can I check the return value / exit status of perl -MCPAN -e?

Tags: bash, perl, return-value, cpan, exit-code

I'm currently writing an installer for my company so we can set up new machines easily. One part of it is a series of CPAN modules that is installed through individual `perl -MCPAN -e 'install "Module::Name"'` commands. I made an array of the modules (about 200) which is installed through a foreach loop in a bash script. However, I now want to check the exit status of the module installation before starting the new one, is this possible? Here's what I tried so far:

```
for i in "${CPANmodules[@]}"
do
    echo -e "\033[1;32mInstalling CPAN module $i \033[0m"
    perl -MCPAN -e "install \"$i\""
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]
    then
        echo "Error installing module $i"
    fi
done
```

I've also tried the following, with no success:

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install "Madeup::Modulename"'
perl -e 'print $?'
```

However, this always returns 0, even if the module doesn't even exist.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a guess: can you do `'install "Madeup::Modulename" or exit 1'`?

Comment: Great suggestion, however, it changes nothing.

Comment: A quick test here with the suggestion from @TomFenech worked on my CentOS 5 machine (after I ran through the CPAN setup as I'd never used it on that machine before).

Comment: It still returns 0 for me. Did you use the exact syntax Tom posted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`failed`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CPAN#failed) command to show all the modules that failed to `make`, `test`, or `install` in the current session. Unfortunately, `failed` doesn't return the number of failures, but simply prints the results to `STDOUT`.

There is probably a better way to do this, but filtering the output with the following hack seems to work:

```
perl -MCPAN -wE '
    CPAN::Shell->install("Foo::Bar");
    open my $buffer, ">", \my $failed or die $!;
    my $stdout = select $buffer;
    CPAN::Shell->failed;
    select $stdout;
    close $buffer;
    exit 1 unless $failed =~ /Nothing failed in this session/'
```

*(Code for redirecting `STDOUT` to a variable taken from [simbabque's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14234815/176646) to another SO question)*

Note that if a module is not found on CPAN, this will return zero, since it would never even get to the `make` phase.

You could also use the [`uptodate`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CPAN#CPAN::Module::uptodate) command, which returns 1 if the specified module is installed and up-to-date:

```
perl -MCPAN -wE '
    $name = "Foo::Bar";
    CPAN::Shell->install($name);
    $mod = CPAN::Shell->expandany($name);
    exit(! defined $mod || ! $mod->uptodate)'
```

This won't work, of course, if you're installing older versions of modules (and I'm not sure about development versions).

---

If you're willing to try a different installer, [`cpanm`](https://metacpan.org/pod/cpanm) actually returns sane values: 0 for successful installs and upgrades, 1 for modules that aren't found or fail to install.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I guess I'll have to switch to cpanm if I want the functionality that I had intended.

Comment: @Bifrost Personally, I *prefer* `cpanm` because it is much less verbose than `cpan` by default, among other things.

Answer (score 0):

Use this form of CPAN install method

```
sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'CPAN::Shell->install("Devel::Cover") or exit 18'
```

Comment: Edit: This always returns 18. Tried it with a madeup name, a module that was already installed, and one that wasn't installed yet (but was installed successfully). All returned 18.